# Django filter: different results in filtering between SQLite and PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, django-queryset

I have a relatively simple query running on a database table; the filter checks the value of 2 date fields and returns a queryset. The fields checked are **authored_report_received** and **subbed_complete**. If authored_report_received has a date set AND subbed_complete has no date set, then a result will be returned.
If both these fields have a date set then no results are returned.
(A simple calculation for the 'days outstanding' between any result returned and the current date is then made.)
This works absolutely fine running locally on a SQLite database but when I upload to heroku to be used with a PostgreSQL database, the filter does not seem to work in that it seems to ignore any date value in the **subbed_complete** field. I do not understand why not. Is there a difference between the way SQLite and PostgreSQL handles the filters? I can't find any docs which indicate this.

```
# views.py
class EpgReportSubeditListView(LoginRequiredMixin, EpgUserPassesTestMixin, ListView):
    """EPG-only: create a list view of reports currently being subedited
    """
    model = Report
    template_name = 'tracker/epg_report_subedit.html'
    context_object_name = 'report_subedit'
    ordering = ['subeditor']

    def get_queryset(self):
        today = datetime.now().date()
        out = []
        for obj in (self.model.objects.filter(subbed_complete__isnull=True) and self.model.objects.filter(authored_report_received__isnull=False)):
            setattr(obj, 'days_diff', (today - obj.authored_report_received).days)
            out.append(obj)
        return out

# models.py
class Report(models.Model):
    """Define fields for Report object (representing a case report)
    """
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reports')
    editor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=False,
                               limit_choices_to={'groups__name': 'editors'},
                               related_name='editor', null=True)
    
    # editing workflow info
    authored_report_received = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    subbed_complete = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    subeditor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=False,
                                  limit_choices_to={'groups__name': 'subeditors'},
                                  related_name='subeditor', null=True, blank=True)
    sent_to_editor = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    edited = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    reporter_queries = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                                        choices=Binary_Choices,
                                        default="n")
    sent_to_deskeditor = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    taken_by_deskeditor = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    deskeditor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=False,
                                   limit_choices_to={'groups__name': 'deskeditors'},
                                   related_name='deskeditor', null=True, blank=True)
    deskedit_complete = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sent_to_counsel = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    received_from_counsel = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_editor_publish_approve = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("epg_home")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.case} | f: {self.filename}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite and PostgreSQL handle dates differently. `subbed_complete` is a `models.DateField` field, but *sqlite3*:

> does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or
> times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are
> capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:

> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

So you should test your code and adjust the query in an another environment with postgresql.

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html